# NetSuite cycle count accuracy formula

Tags: netsuite

I am attempting to build a saved search that measures our inventory cycle counts. I am using the saved transaction search to do this. I have been able to build out everything I want with the exception of Count Accuracy.

Here is what I have:

```
sum(Case when {transactionlinetype} = 'Adjusted Quantity' then abs({quantity})  Else 0 END) / 
sum(Case when {transactionlinetype} = 'Snapshot Quantity' then {quantity} Else 0 END)
```

The goal is to get the % value of Item counted and divide it by the number of issues.

To provide the working example: I have 10 items to count, each item has 10 on hand so I have 100 items counted, 3 of those items had issues so my result should be 3%

I have looked for answers but have not been successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what result you're getting, or what the error is, but when I tried with your formula I got a 'possible divide by 0' error.  The solution to this is to wrap the denominator in a `nullif()` function, so you could use:

```
sum(Case when {transactionlinetype} = 'Adjusted Quantity' then abs({quantity})  Else 0 END) /  
nullif(sum(Case when {transactionlinetype} = 'Snapshot Quantity' then {quantity} Else 0 END),0)
```

Comment: It wouldn't let me get far enough to get an error code, it would break and say go back. This answer worked though, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is like a subquery which is not possible in NS saved search.

Comment: From a Inventory count record, I am trying to get the sum of differences  divided by the sum of items to report on Inventory Accuracy. I have just been exporting and reporting outside of netsuite but it would be nice to do it in NetSuite if possible. Thanks!